# Personal AI assistant program not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I have gotten this code from an article on the internet and have finished troubleshooting it, now it runs with an exit code 0. It doesn't do anything, like greet or ask for an input or nothing. It just runs and gives the exit code.

I have had problems with installing ecapture, it seems a lot of people with Python 3.9 have had this problem so I have commented it out.

This is the source from which I got the code.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-ai-personal-assistant-using-python-f57247b4494b

```
# Press Shift+F10 to execute it or replace it with your code.
# Press Double Shift to search everywhere for classes, files, tool windows, actions, and settings.


def print_hi(name):
    # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
    print(f'Hi, {name}')  # Press Ctrl+F8 to toggle the breakpoint.


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')

# See PyCharm help at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import time
import subprocess
"""from ecapture import ecapture as ec"""
import wolframalpha
import json
import requests

engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voice=engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', 'voices[0].id')

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    hour=datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak("Hello,Good Morning")
        print("Hello,Good Morning")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour <18:
        speak("Hello, Good Afternoon")
        print("Hello, Good Afternoon")
    else:
        speak ("Hello, Good Evening")
        print ("Hello, Good Evening")
    def takeCommand():
        r=sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print ("Listening...")
            audio=r.listen(source)

            try:
                statement=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-uk')
                print(f"user said:{statement}\n")

            except Exception as e:
                speak ("Run that by me again")
                return "None"
            return statement

    print ("Loading your AI personal assistant G-One")
    speak ("Loading your AI personal assistant G-One")
    wishMe()


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        while True:
            speak("How may I be of assistance?")
            statement = takeCommand().lower()
            if statement==0:
                continue

    if "good bye" in statement or "ok bye" in statement or "that'll be all" in statement:
        speak ('your personal assistant G-One is shutting down, Good bye')
        print ('your personal assistant G-One is shutting down, Good bye')

    if 'wikipedia' in statement:
        speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
        statement =statement.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results =wikipedia.summary(statement, sentences=3)
        speak ("According to Wikipedia")
        print (results)
        speak (results)


    elif 'open youtube' in statement:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.youtube.com")
        speak ("youtube is now open")
        time.sleep(5)

    elif 'open google' in statement:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
        speak ("Google chrome is now open")
        time.sleep(5)

    elif 'open gmail' in statement:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("gmail.com")
        speak ("Gmail is now open")
        time.sleep(5)

    elif time in statement:
        strTime=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        speak(f"the time is {strTime}")

    elif 'news' in statement:
        news = webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRFZxYUdjU0FtVnVHZ0pKVGlnQVAB?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen")
        speak('Here are some headlines from Google news')
        time.sleep(6)


    elif 'search' in statement:
        statement = statement.replace("search","")
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(statement)
        time.sleep(5)

    elif 'ask' in statement:
        speak('I can answer to computational and geographical questions, which of these would you like to ask now')
        question=takeCommand()
        app_id="LURX84-VPJ6LEHWXV" """Wolfram App ID"""
        client = wolframalpha.Client('R2K75H-7ELALHR35X')
        res = client.query(question)
        answer = next(res.results).text
        speak (answer)
        print (answer)

    elif 'who are you' in statement or 'what are your capabilities' in statement:
        speak ('I am Arthur, and am still in my infancy. I am capable of accomplishing minor tasks at this point in time such as'
               'opening google products such as youtube, gmail, and chrome.'
               'I have other functions such as relating the time, taking pictures,searching wikipedia, relating the weather'
               'as well as reading headlines from google news')

    elif 'who made you' in statement or 'who built you' in statement or 'who discovered you' in statement:
        speak("I was built by Ahmed Hamadto")
        print ("I was built by Ahmed Hamadto")

    """include the weather part of the AI here"""

    if 'log off' in statement or 'lights out' in statement:
        speak ("You've got 10 seconds to clear things up")
        subprocess.call(["shutdown","/1"])

    time.sleep(3)


"""    elif 'camera'in statement or 'take a photo' in statement or 'snap this' in statement:
        ec.capture(0,"robo camera","img.jpg")"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. You have put `if __name__ == "__main__"` inside your `wishMe` function. Put is outside and it should work fine.

Comment: Moreover the `takecommand` function should be outside the `wishme()` function

Comment: @GameDev, That is not necessary. You can nest functions in python.